# jQuery Change variable value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function. It looks like this

```
function open_file (filename) {
  'use strict';
  var file;
  $.ajax(filename, {
    dataType: 'text',
    success:  function (data) {
      file = data;
      alert(file);
    }
  });
  return file;
}
```

The alert displays the text that is being stored in the file, just like I want it to. However, when it is time to return the value to the function caller, it returns an undeclared value.

How can I set the value of a variable using jQuery, but with the variable's value to be used outside of jQuery?

**EDIT**: I've read the duplicate question, but I'm still confused about how the call back is working as I try to trace it through the call stack. I will keep working on trying to sort this mess out.

Comment: Far better duplicate and canonical answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Dear humans of the future. I'm the one who asked this question, and @charlietfl has provided the link that helped me. You should click on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
function open_file (filename) {
  'use strict';
 return  $.ajax(filename, {
    dataType: 'text'
  });

}
```

Comment: Still undefined return value when called in another function.

Comment: you may try the solutions of this ques : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success

Comment: Returns the promise...missing the part showing how to get data from the promise